# Count of co-prime pairs from two arrays in less than O(n^2) complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I came to this problem in a challenge. 
There are two arrays A and B both of size of N and we need to return the count of pairs (A[i],B[j]) where `gcd(A[i],B[j])==1` and `A[i] != B[j]`. 
I could only think of brute force approach which exceeded time limit for few test cases.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        if(__gcd(a[i],b[j])==1) {
             printf("%d %d\n", a[i], b[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you advice time efficient algorithm to solve this.

Edit: Not able to share question link as this was from a hiring challenge. Adding the constraints and input/output format as I remember.

Input -

- First line will contain N, the number of elements present in both arrays.
- Second line will contain N space separated integers, elements of array A.
- Third line will contain N space separated integers, elements of array B.

Output -

- The count of pairs A[i],A[j] as per the conditions.

Constraints -

- 1 <= N <= 10^5
- 1 < A[i],B[j] <= 10^9 where i,j < N

Comment: Is there a bound on the size of the elements of A and B?

Comment: Why the `i != j` condition?

Comment: @PaulHankin That's asking if `n` is bounded, which would make any solution `O(1)`.

Comment: Sorry,Initially I thought that this question can be done by Euler's totient function but I was unable to figure out any way to do that with it. Can you please share the question link so that I can help.

Comment: @Nelfeal he meant sizes of the *elements*, not the array itself.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Oh right, I was wondering how a bound on the numbers themselves could help, but I guess it does if you do prime factorization or something similar.

Comment: Clearly, any O(n^2) algorithm is going to be too slow. You need to somehow make use of the fact that you don't need to *produce* the pairs, just *count* them, and design an O(n log n) or better algorithm.

Comment: thank you for helping out, i added the constraints and ip in the qeustion
@ PaulHankin I added the size contraints
@ Nelfeal That was a typo, corrected it, thank you
@ PraveenOjha I don't have the link, but i added few details

Comment: @kfx maybe i don't remember the condition correctly, anyway challenge is over, i just want to know about any faster algo, we can ignore that condition :)
apologies, you are right, it is A[i] != B[j]

Comment: `gcd(A[i],B[j])==1` implies `A[i] != B[j]` since `1 < A[i], B[j]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step is to use [Eratosthenes sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to calculate the prime numbers up to `sqrt(10^9)`. This sieve can then be used to quickly find all prime factors of any number less than `10^9` (see the `getPrimeFactors(...)` function in the code sample below).

Next, for each `A[i]` with prime factors `p0, p1, ..., pk`, we compute all possible sub-products `X` - `p0, p1, p0p1, p2, p0p2, p1p2, p0p1p2, p3, p0p3, ..., p0p1p2...pk` and count them in map `cntp[X]`. Effectively, the map `cntp[X]` tells us the number of elements `A[i]` divisible by `X`, where `X` is a product of prime numbers to the power of 0 or 1. So for example, for the number `A[i] = 12`, the prime factors are `2, 3`. We will count `cntp[2]++`, `cntp[3]++` and `cntp[6]++`.

Finally, for each `B[j]` with prime factors `p0, p1, ..., pk`, we again compute all possible sub-products `X` and use the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count all non-coprime pairs `C_j` (i.e. the number of `A[i]`s that share at least one prime factor with `B[j]`). The numbers `C_j` are then subtracted from the total number of pairs - `N*N` to get the final answer.

Note: the Inclusion-exclusion principle looks like this:

```
C_j = (cntp[p0] + cntp[p1] + ... + cntp[pk]) -
      (cntp[p0p1] + cntp[p0p2] + ... + cntp[pk-1pk]) +
      (cntp[p0p1p2] + cntp[p0p1p3] + ... + cntp[pk-2pk-1pk]) -
      ...
```

and accounts for the fact that in `cntp[X]` and `cntp[Y]` we could have counted the same number `A[i]` twice, given that it is divisible by both `X` and `Y`.

Here is a possible C++ implementation of the algorithm, which produces the same results as the naive O(n^2) algorithm by OP:

```
// get prime factors of a using pre-generated sieve
std::vector<int> getPrimeFactors(int a, const std::vector<int> & primes) {
    std::vector<int> f;
    for (auto p : primes) {
        if (p > a) break;
        if (a % p == 0) {
            f.push_back(p);
            do {
                a /= p;
            } while (a % p == 0);
        }
    }
    if (a > 1) f.push_back(a);

    return f;
}

// find coprime pairs A_i and B_j
// A_i and B_i <= 1e9
void solution(const std::vector<int> & A, const std::vector<int> & B) {
    // generate prime sieve
    std::vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);

    for (int i = 3; i*i <= 1e9; ++i) {
        bool isPrime = true;
        for (auto p : primes) {
            if (i % p == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    int N = A.size();

    struct Entry {
        int n = 0;
        int64_t p = 0;
    };

    // cntp[X] - number of times the product X can be expressed
    // with prime factors of A_i
    std::map<int64_t, int64_t> cntp;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        auto f = getPrimeFactors(A[i], primes);

        // count possible products using non-repeating prime factors of A_i
        std::vector<Entry> x;
        x.push_back({ 0, 1 });

        for (auto p : f) {
            int k = x.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                int nn = x[i].n + 1;
                int64_t pp = x[i].p*p;

                ++cntp[pp];
                x.push_back({ nn, pp });
            }
        }
    }

    // use Inclusion–exclusion principle to count non-coprime pairs
    // and subtract them from the total number of prairs N*N

    int64_t cnt = N; cnt *= N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        auto f = getPrimeFactors(B[i], primes);

        std::vector<Entry> x;
        x.push_back({ 0, 1 });

        for (auto p : f) {
            int k = x.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                int nn = x[i].n + 1;
                int64_t pp = x[i].p*p;

                x.push_back({ nn, pp });

                if (nn % 2 == 1) {
                    cnt -= cntp[pp];
                } else {
                    cnt += cntp[pp];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("cnt = %d\n", (int) cnt);
}
```

[Live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d35e9ee0d6b2208a)

I cannot estimate the complexity analytically, but here are some profiling result on my laptop for different `N` and uniformly random `A[i]` and `B[j]`:

```
For N = 1e2, takes ~0.02 sec
For N = 1e3, takes ~0.05 sec
For N = 1e4, takes ~0.38 sec
For N = 1e5, takes ~3.80 sec
```

For comparison, the O(n^2) approach takes:

```
For N = 1e2, takes ~0.00 sec
For N = 1e3, takes ~0.15 sec
For N = 1e4, takes ~15.1 sec
For N = 1e5, takes too long, didn't wait to finish
```

Comment: With `s^2` the upper bound on the elements of `A` and `B`, building the sieve is `O(s log log s)`. Factoring each element is at most `O(log log s)`, so for all elements, it's `O(n log log s)`. If you only take into account distinct prime factors (because you can), there are less than `2^(log log s) = (log s)^(log 2) < s` sub-products for any element, so for all elements, computing the sub-products (and counting all non-coprime pairs) is at most `O(s)`. Summing all that up gives an (over)estimate `O((s+n) log log s)`, and if `s ~ n`, `O(n log log n)`.

Comment: That said, the problem states an upper bound on `n`, which is stupid since it makes any solution automatically `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the complexity analysis. What do you mean by "it makes any solutions automatically O(1)"? You still need to iterate over the elements, so it cannot be less than O(n) in any case.

Comment: Let `M` be the upper bound on `n` (`M = 10^5` in the question). Any solution will have a runtime as an increasing function of `n`; let `f` be that function for any particular solution, so its runtime is `f(n)`. The problem that the upper bound introduces is that this particular solution will never have a runtime greater than `f(M)`, which means you can simply say that its complexity is `O(f(M))`. And because `f(M)` is constant, that's equivalent to `O(1)`. It might be a very large constant, but it defeats the purpose of complexity analysis (where `n` is supposed to grow indefinitely).

Answer (score 0):

Python Implementation:

```
    import math
    from collections import defaultdict

    def sieve(MAXN):
        spf = [0 for i in range(MAXN)]
        spf[1] = 1
        for i in range(2, MAXN):
            spf[i] = i
        for i in range(4, MAXN, 2):
            spf[i] = 2
        for i in range(3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(MAXN))):
            if (spf[i] == i):
                for j in range(i * i, MAXN, i):
                    if (spf[j] == j):
                        spf[j] = i
        return(spf)

    def getFactorization(x,spf):
        ret = list()
        while (x != 1):
            ret.append(spf[x])
            x = x // spf[x]
        return(list(set(ret)))

    def coprime_pairs(N,A,B):
        MAXN=max(max(A),max(B))+1
        spf=sieve(MAXN)
        cntp=defaultdict(int)
        for i in range(N):
            f=getFactorization(A[i],spf)
            x=[[0,1]]
            for p in f:
                k=len(x)
                for i in range(k):
                    nn=x[i][0]+1
                    pp=x[i][1]*p
                    cntp[pp]+=1
                    x.append([nn,pp])
        cnt=0
        for i in range(N):
            f=getFactorization(B[i],spf)
            x=[[0,1]]
            for p in f:
                k=len(x)
                for i in range(k):
                    nn=x[i][0]+1
                    pp=x[i][1]*p
                    x.append([nn,pp])
                    if(nn%2==1):
                        cnt+=cntp[pp]
                    else:
                        cnt-=cntp[pp]
        return(N*N-cnt)

    import random
    N=10001
    A=[random.randint(1,N) for _ in range(N)]
    B=[random.randint(1,N) for _ in range(N)]
    print(coprime_pairs(N,A,B))
```