# Find the no of pairs with gcd 1 efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, math, data-structures

Given 2 arrays of length n, a and b, I want to find the number of pairs such that Gcd(a[i], b[j]) == 1 in less than O(n^2).

EDIT: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957088/count-of-co-prime-pairs-from-two-arrays-in-less-than-on2-complexity)

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of numbers in $O(n)$, you can use the following method to do it in $O(nlog(n))$ (from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-an-array-element-that-is-co-prime-with-all-others/)):

> Efficient approach: An efficient solution is to generate all the prime factors of integers in the given array. Using **hash**, store the count of every element which is a prime factor of any of the number in the array. If the element does not contain any common prime factor with other elements, it always forms a co-prime pair with other elements.
> For generating prime factors please go through the article [Prime Factorization using Sieve in O(log n)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-factorization-using-sieve-olog-n-multiple-queries/).

You can find the implementation of the algorithm in C++  in that source as well.

Moreover, if you are limitted for te precomputation, you cn use `O(\sqrt(n))` for prime factoring, and your algorithm will be in `O(n\sqrt(n))`.